# How to merging rows in a spark data set to combine a string column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to merge two or more rows in a dataset into one. The grouping has to be done based on an `id` column. The column to be merged is a string. I need to get a comma-separated string in the merged column. How do I achieve this is Java?
Input rows

```
col1,col2  
1,abc  
2,pqr  
1,abc1  
3,xyz
2,pqr1
```

Expected output :

```
col1, col2  
1, "abc,abc1"  
2, "pqr,pqr1"  
3, xyz
```

Comment: pleace share data, code and expected output.

Comment: Edited to add an example of what is expected

Comment: Your example is unreadable by the way

Answer (score 4):

To aggregate two separate columns:

```
your_data_frame
    .withColumn("aggregated_column", concat_ws(",", col("col1"), col("col2"))
```

Just in case, here is what to import besides the usual stuff

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
```

**Edit**

If you want to aggregate an arbitrary number of columns that you know by name, you can do it this way:

```
String[] column_names = {"c1", "c2", "c3"};
Column[] columns = Arrays.asList(column_names)
            .stream().map(x -> col(x))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toArray(new Column[0]);
data_frame
    .withColumn("agg", concat_ws(",", columns));
```

**Edit #2: group by and concat**

In case you want to group by a column "ID" and aggregate another column, you can do it this way:

```
dataframe
    .groupBy("ID")
    .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list(col("col1")) ))
```

Comment: myDS.groupBy("ID").agg(functions.concat_ws(",",myDS.col("THEME"))); This is what I did but  I see an exception which says expression THEME is neither present in the groupBy , nor is part of the aggregate. I want to aggregate the same column from 2 or more  different rows which have the same ID valu.e

Comment: concat_ws is not an aggregation function. That's why you get this error. To the best of my knowledge, the only solution is to use functions.collect_list, that will aggregate your values into a list and then apply a UDF (user defined function).

Comment: Well, turns out it was possible without a udf. concat_ws can work with a string array column. I added a solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use groupBy and concat_ws

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("col1").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list("col2")))
```