# How to concat all column values in a spark dataframe into a String in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to concat all the values in a column to make a string out of it with comma seperated values. To do that in Scala, I wrote the following code:

```
val pushLogIds = incLogIdDf.select($"interface_log_id").collect().map(_.getInt(0).toString).mkString(",")
```

I am new to Python and after selecting the values in the column, I am unable to find a logic to Python to concat all the column values to a String after collecting them.

```
final_log_id_list = logidf.select("interface_log_id").collect()
```

Ex:

```
interface_log_id
----------------
     1
     2
     3
     4

Output: a variable of String containing '1,2,3,4'
```

Could anyone let me know how to concat all the column values of a dataframe into a single String of comma separated values.

Comment: I had imported `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` so that the python builtins such as `min` , `max` etc are not overridden , hence every pyspark builtin needs an `F` prefix for me. You can ignore the F if you import without an alias

Comment: Got it. One last thing, to this will still result the output in a column in a dataframe. To conver it to a String, I did this `>>> a = str(df.select('value').agg(F.concat_ws(",", F.collect_list(F.col('value')))))
>>> a
'DataFrame[concat_ws(,, collect_list(value)): string]'` and it it still doesn't yild a String and instead comes a dataframe.

Comment: for a scalar you can do `df.agg(F.concat_ws(",",F.collect_list(F.col("A"))).alias('A')).first()[0]`

Comment: Can you post this as an answer ?

Comment: Posted , the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870827/how-to-merging-rows-in-a-spark-data-set-to-combine-a-string-column) answer is similar but cant say its an exact dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For converting a column to a single string , you can first collect the column as a list using `collect_list` and then concat with `,` , finally get the first value as a scalar using `first`:

```
df.agg(F.concat_ws(",",F.collect_list(F.col("interface_log_id")))).first()[0]
#'1,2,3,4'
```

Another way is collect_list and then using python `','.join` with `map` for numeric columns

```
','.join(map(str,df.agg(F.collect_list(F.col("A"))).first()[0]))
```

Adding benchmarks:

```
%timeit ','.join(map(str,df.agg(F.collect_list(F.col("A"))).first()[0]))
#9.38 s ± 133 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.agg(F.concat_ws(",",F.collect_list(F.col("A")))).first()[0]
#9.46 s ± 246 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This works and what I am trying to achieve. I believe [0] is the column index ?

Comment: @Metadata yes `first()` gives you the row object , `[0]` gives you the first value of the row

Comment: @Metadata added another way , you can check for performance and use either

Comment: ^for `spark2.4` instead of `concat_ws`, id say use `array_join`

Comment: `array_join` works too: `%timeit df.select(F.array_join(F.collect_list(F.col("A").cast("string")),",")).first()[0]` , `9.87 s ± 253 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: Great.. I will test thm both and post the time taken by each one.